# Clang compiled from source cannot find -lomp

Tags: c, ubuntu, clang, openmp, llvm

I've compiled LLVM from source including clang and openmp. When I try to compile a simple C program using openmp with the produced clang binary though I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lomp: No such file or directory`. However, `libomp.so` is very clearly in `llvm-project/build/lib`, and the build finished with no errors.

I've tried adding `path/to/llvm-project/build/lib` with `-L` but this doesn't change behavior. The command I'm running is:

`./build/bin/clang -O3 -static omp_test.c -I /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include/ -L ./build/lib/ -fopenmp=libomp`

And the C file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Hello from process: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is clang not able to find libomp here?

Comment: it's included implicitly from `-fopenmp=libomp`. If I add `-lomp` explicitly I just get the same linker error twice.

Comment: Please add a tag for your platform. Linux distro if needed.

Comment: I'm running this in a ubuntu docker container on top of gentoo.

Comment: remove `-static` from the compiler options. Here, `ld` is searching for `libomp.a` and you only have `libomp.so`

Comment: Removing `-static` makes it work, but static binaries are a requirement for my use case. I take it I'll need to figure out a way to generate a `libomp.a` from the LLVM build then?

Comment: There's probably a configuration option for LLVM to build it with static libraries. You'll have to do that